# Converting decimal xml to decimal with 2 decimal points with XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery

I am a newbie to xml and XQuery and I have question about converting numbers.

I have flat file which is being converted to xml using Stylus Studio converter. Then I use XQuery to pull in the various tables that I need.

One of the issue is the currency input data.

Flat file data : 00004700000 This is $47000
(In the converter source is defined string and destination is defined decimal)

In XQuery I can divide the number 00004700000 by 100 and BUT end up with 47000.

What I'd like is the output to be 47000.00 so that I can display it as it is with 2 decimal points.

Value 000038715 divide by 100 gives 387.15 which works fine.

This is what I do in XQuery:

```
<CREDIT_LIMIT>
{$cust/CREDIT_LIMIT div 100}
</CREDIT_LIMIT>
```

Is there a way to do this to get .00 on the output of XQuery?

Many thanks.
Pravin

PS
Don't know much about xslt!

Answer (score 3):

you have the function format-number for this :

```
<CREDIT_LIMIT>
{format-number($cust/CREDIT_LIMIT div 100,".00")}
</CREDIT_LIMIT>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

```
<CREDIT_LIMIT>
  {$x idiv 100 }.{$x mod 100 idiv 10}{$x mod 10}
</CREDIT_LIMIT>
```

where `$x` is the number to be represented in the desired decimal format.